# When pthread_join called, I get an error "Resource deadlock avoided"

Tags: pthreads

As I mentioned in the title, when I try to join the threads, I get an error.

m_threadid : 4615464704, pthread_join error : Resource deadlock avoided, thread name : NetworkWorker

I was wondering what kind of situation it is and any suggestion on fixing this.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code?

Comment: kinda too long and too complicated to just cut and paste on here lol... I was just wondering why that error is caused normally Thx

Answer (score 23):

This error (`EDEADLK`) results when you have a closed loop of threads trying to join each other.  In the simplest cases, this is either a thread calling `pthread_join()` on itself, or two threads calling `pthread_join()` on each other.